# Smarty, different directory from other files

Tags: html, smarty

I'm using smarty for my site and I'm wanting to make an admin panel, however I want to do the admin panel on /admin but all the templates and such try and load /admin/templates/css and not /templates/css, I'm not sure how to fix this... Any advice?

I have my css/javascript etc... Like this

```
<link href="templates/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you wrote the answer yourself. You're using a relative path, so it looks in the folder you're currently in. Use an absolute path instead:

```
<link href="/templates/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```